# Regex to validate company names

Tags: regex

I have this RegEx to validate a few things, unfortunately it won't validate P.C. only P.C - I tried adding {0,1} to each period but it still will not validate. Any ideas?

(new-line characters for readability)

```
/(^|\s)Corporation\.{0,1}(^|$)|
 (^|\s)Corp\.{0,1}(^|$)|
 (^|\s)Inc\.{0,1}(^|$)|
 (^|\s)Incorporated\.{0,1}(^|$)|
 (^|\s)Company\.{0,1}(^|$)|
 (^|\s)(^|$)|
 (^|\s)LTD\.{0,1}(^|$)|
 (^|\s)PLLC\.{0,1}(^|$)|
 (^|\s)P\.{0,1}C\.{0,1}(^|$)/ig;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to match the beginning of the string at the end of each option?

Comment: I think that instead of `(^|\s)` you want to use `\b` which is "word boundary" which is more clear and is zero-width.

Comment: Also, instead of `{0,1}` you want `?`.

Comment: You wait until you start dealing with international companies…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your regex:

```
/(?:^|\s)(?:Corporation|Corp|Inc|Incorporated|Company|LTD|PLLC|P\.C)\.?$/ig;
```

- `{0,1}` can be replaced by `?`
- Repetition can be eliminated with some grouping.
- This doesn't make much sense: `(^|$)`.  You are requiring either a beginning of a line or an end of a line to occur right after a match.  This is functionally the same as requiring the match to be at the end of the line, so I just replaced it with `$`.
- When you need to group things, use non-capturing groups `(?:...)` unless you need to grab that part of the match.  They are more efficient.

All that being said, your original pattern should have matched `P.C.` at the end of a line. The problem may be something with your input data or the way you are using the regex.

Comment: You should switch `Inc` and `Incorporated` so that it doesn't match too early. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @MatthewGreen, that won't matter since the match must occur at the end of the line.